# HTML list to array

Tags: php, list

How can I parse multilevel HTML list and get an array by php

---

I am trying this code

```
$text='<ol>
            <li>31</li>
            <li>32</li>
            <li>33</li>
            <li>34</li>
            <li>
                <ol>
                    <li>341</li>
                    <li>342</li>
                    <li>343</li>
                    <li>344</li>
                    <li>
                        <ol>
                            <li>3441</li>
                            <li>3442</li>
                            <li>3443</li>
                            <li>3444</li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>';


$html = str_get_html($text);
foreach( $html->find('ol') as $ol)
{
    $array[] = $ol->innertext; 
}

print_r($array);
```

Here is the result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
            <li>31</li>
            <li>32</li>
            <li>33</li>
            <li>34</li>
            <li>
                <ol>
                    <li>341</li>

                    <li>342</li>
                    <li>343</li>
                    <li>344</li>
                    <li>
                        <ol>
                            <li>3441</li>
                            <li>3442</li>

                            <li>3443</li>
                            <li>3444</li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>

    [1] => 
                    <li>341</li>

                    <li>342</li>
                    <li>343</li>
                    <li>344</li>
                    <li>
                        <ol>
                            <li>3441</li>
                            <li>3442</li>

                            <li>3443</li>
                            <li>3444</li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>

    [2] => 
                            <li>3441</li>
                            <li>3442</li>

                            <li>3443</li>
                            <li>3444</li>

)
```

But I need something Like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
               (
              [0] => Array
                         (
                          [0] =>....
```

Answer (score 1):

With an [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks a lot , but this parses HTML list like $OL[0],$OL[1],$OL[2] ..., I need multilevel parser like this  $OL[0][0],$OL[0][1] and $OL[1][0], $OL[1][1], $OL[1][2] etc...

Comment: So you'll have to apply a bit of elbow grease then.

Answer (score 1):

It's all in there. Do a `var_export` on the `$html` object to see the entire object structure. To get the data into the array that you want, you might have to use the tree walking routines (i.e., firstChild, nextSibling, etc.), and build your array.